# How to import specific lines from dat file

Tags: file-io, import, sas

I've got a .dat file with numbers that I need imported into a SAS dataset. However, there's plenty of information that I do *not* need, and I only want specific lines of data (e.g. every 6th line starting from line 1000, until I have 100 observations). I also require a unique identifier based on what is displayed on the first line.

So for example, the .dat file contains this:

```
DATANOTREQUIRED
DATANOTREQUIRED
DATANOTREQUIRED
UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_1_#
123.4,
123.5,
124.0,
124.1
DATANOTREQUIRED
DATANOTREQUIRED
DATANOTREQUIRED
UPDATE AAA_1111111__Q_BBBBBB_0_2_#
125.1,
126.0,
127.1,
130.0
```

What I want the eventual SAS dataset to look like is this

```
Identifier | Value 

X.1.       | 124.1

X.2.       | 130.0
```

I'm using the infile in SAS and using input to point to line 1000 but I'm stuck and cannot get the SAS dataset I want. (Updated code based on contributors below)

```
data work.test;
infile '\\filepath\mydatasource.dat' dsd firstobs=1042 truncover;
input #8 ID :$40.
#4 Value1 :8.;
run;
```

but what I'm seeing now is that the header lines are appearing fine, but the first observation has a . and instead the first data value is appearing for the 2nd header line.

```
ID                                      | Value1 

UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_1_#       | .

UPDATE AAA_1111111__Q_BBBBBB_0_2_#      | 124.1
```

Comment: Do you always have the same number of lines between each header row? What logic do you need to use to construct your unique ID?

Comment: Yes always the same number of lines between each header row.

Logic for the unique ID is this:

Always starts with X

Followed by the 2nd last number in the header row (in the case of UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_1_# , the number is zero. Where it is zero then use a .)

Followed by the last number in the header row. In the example above, this is the number 1.

Followed by the character where the # is in the header row. Where it is # then use . (this can normally be a singular alpha character like A B or C etc)

So unique ID for UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_1_# 
is
X.1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example assuming that you have the same number of rows between each header row:

```
data want;
if _n_ > 2 then stop; /*Stop after we've output 2 rows */
infile cards firstobs=6; /*Skip the first 5 lines in the file*/
input #1 @8 ID :$32.
      #5 myvar :8.;
cards;
UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_1_#
123.4,
123.5,
124.0,
124.1
UPDATE AAA_1111111__Q_BBBBBB_0_2_#
125.1,
126.0,
127.1,
130.0
UPDATE AAA_1111111_Q_BBBBBB_0_3_#
123.4,
123.5,
124.0,
124.1
UPDATE AAA_1111111__Q_BBBBBB_0_4_#
125.1,
126.0,
127.1,
130.0
;
run;
```

Comment: infile 'mydatasource.dat'
dsd firstobs=1042 truncover;
input #8 ID :$40.
#8 @1046 p1 :8.;
run;
I can get the ID fine now, but the data which starts at line 1046 and happens every 8th line is giving me blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FIRSTOBS= option to skip the beginning of the file.
If there are always 5 records per block you could just read them individually.

```
data want;
  infile rawdata dsd firstobs=1000 truncover;
  input id :$40. (4*value) (/) ;
run;
```

Or you could do something like this that should allow for a variable number of values per id and just keep the last one.

```
data want;
  infile rawdata dsd firstobs=1000 end=eof; 
  input @ ;
  length id $32 value 8 ;
  retain id value;
  if _infile_ =: 'UPDATE' then do;
    if _n_ > 1 then output;
    id = scan(_infile_,-1,' ');
  end;
  else input value;
  if eof and _n_ > 1 then output;
run;
```